# iOS Swift displaying character by character from a string array in UILabel.text

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift

I an array with multiple strings that make up a story. I was wondering how to display the string letter by letter like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1w8FCtpVXM). I would also like to make it so that if they press the button before the string is finished loading, it displays the entire string. Like that of a game.

I would preferably like to make it a function since I am going to use this hundreds of times.  I am using Swift 2.0.

```
let myArray = [
"This is my first index", 
"This is my second index", 
"This is my third index",
"...and so on and so forth..."
]
var i : Int = 0

@IBAction func storyButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
storyLabel.text = myArray[i] // Would like to display array index letter by letter when the button is pressed.
i++ //Loading next index in myArray
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You want to concatenate the text onto the label's text letter by letter?

Comment: Yes. as shown in the video  https://youtu.be/z1w8FCtpVXM?t=6s

Comment: This does work with letter by letter but I am trying to use it within my Label.text and it is giving me an error.  How can I use label's text property instead of the UITextView?